# Combobox displaying duplicate items

Tags: c#, sql, combobox

I have a combo box that I am binding from a sql server database. I am binding one column from the database into the combo box. The problem is that I get the same item showing up in there several times. I am querying from a stored procedure. Let me know if there is anything obvious that I am missing. Thanks

```
public void BindComboBox()
{
   _dsinventory = new DataSet();
   _dsinventory = dbAccess.ExecuteQuery(InventoryOutputQuery.ComboBox_Type());
   cmbType.ItemSource = _dsinventory.Tables[0].DefaultView;
   cmbType.DisplayMemberPath = _dsinventory.Tables[0].Columns[Type].ToString();
}
```

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint in this method and see how many times it is being called ?

Comment: yeah, im not exactly sure what it is doing, when it runs, the
    cmbType.ItemSource = _dsinventory.Tables[0].DefaultView; line shows the count as 0 and then when i continue to the next line, the count for the combo box is 144.

Comment: dont forget to mark answer as accpeted if you got the info you want..

Answer (score 2):

try distinct keyword in you select query

```
 Select distinct columnname form table
```

Answer (score 0):

`DISTINCT` should only be used when you are sure that the query is all fine.

Double check the query you are using, and then go for `DISTINCT`.